# NSURLRequest timeout error code

Tags: objective-c, web-services, mobile, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

When I issue an NSURLRequest and I get back a timeout error code (NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001) what exactly does this mean? Does this mean that:

```
  A) My request reached my web server, but the server took too long to issue a response?
  B) My request did not reach the server in time (implying heavy congestion in network)
  C) The server did issue a response, but the response data just did not get back to my client 
     app in time.

      OR....

  D) ALL OF THE ABOVE.
```

My intuition and common sense tells me the answer is D, but I could be wrong. Finally, if the answer is D, is there anyway to differentiate between the above scenarios? I would like to take different actions based on where exactly in the network flow my response is....

Comment: What does the `userInfo` of the error tell you?

Comment: It does not tell me much other than the generic your request timed out message.

Comment: 2014-03-27 22:03:53.891 SDKSampleApp[833:60b] Error User Info: {
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "https://....";
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "https://....";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "The request timed out.";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 \"The request timed out.\" UserInfo=0xaf8a0f0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https:..., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https:..., NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}";
}

Comment: I dotted out the URL's, but is there anything I am supposed to be able to decipher from that?

Comment: It is hard to know why the timeout happened, but it's likely that `B` is not happening, or you would get a different error (look at all the possible error codes for the `NSURLErrorDomain`).  If you have access to the server, peek at its logs.  If not, take a look at the knobs on `NSURLRequest`, particularly `timeoutInterval` and see if that helps track down the problem.

Comment: Sounds good thanks for the insight, but basically in a timeout error, your request has definitely reached the server. Its just your request is either timing out at the server side (via processing/downloading) resulting in no response. Or your request just can't come back to you in time....

Comment: Actually @JodyHagins you are wrong. I simulated a 100% packet loss scenario using network developer tools and the error I get back is a timeout error, NSURLRequest is not differentiating between the above scenarios. In any case, if the response does not come back, it just says its a timeout, which really sucks :(

Comment: It's not the first time, and won't be the last time either.

Comment: Network errors are tricky, and it's supposed to return one of about a half-dozen other errors depending on why the connection can't be established or breaks.  Anyway, I'd be interested to see the code you are executing... and if that error you get from the higher level abstraction is not good enough for you, you can always use the socket API...

Comment: You never said how you were initiating the connection, but if you are using `NSURLSession` you need to heed this note from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html).  Specifically, point #5 under `Life Cycle of a URL Session with System-Provided Delegates` and point #13 under `Life Cycle of a URL Session with Custom Delegates ` which says...

Comment: **Note**: `NSURLSession` does not report server errors through the error parameter. The only errors your app receives through the error parameter are client-side errors, such as being unable to resolve the hostname or connect to the host. The error codes are described in URL Loading System Error Codes.
Server-side errors are reported through the HTTP status code in the `NSHTTPURLResponse` object. For more information, read the documentation for the `NSHTTPURLResponse` and `NSURLResponse` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request timed out - it means simply that. We sent a request off to the server and never got any reply.

So could be any one of A, B or C.